# Scroll to specific row in Datatable API

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to scroll until specific row in my datatable like this:

https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/api_scrolling.html

This is my code:

```
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/form-builder.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        ....
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                tableEntityList = $('#accentityListTable').DataTable({      
                    "ordering": false,  
                    "scrollY":"120px",
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "paging":false, 
                    "dom":'<<"top"i>ft>',
                    "deferRender":true,
                    "scroller":true,    
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {"targets": [ 0 ],"visible": false}
                    ],
                    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
                        if ( data[ 3 ] == "Inp" )
                            $(row).css('color', 'green')
                        else 
                            $(row).css('color', 'red')

                        if ( data[7] > 0 ) $(row).css('font-weight', 'bold')                        
                    },
                    "initComplete": function () {
                        alert("first");
                        this.api().row( 2 ).scrollTo();
                        alert("second");
                    }           

                });
    })
</script>
```

The first alert appears:

```
alert("first");
```

But the second one, doesnt:

```
alert("second");
```

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You're using two jQuery libraries, remove one that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is probably with your use of 'this'. In this case, I think it actually references the callback function, and not the DataTable. I'm not sure if you could pass it as a parameter to the callback function somehow, but if you create a reference to the DataTable outside the callback function's scope, you can access it by that variable.

Comment: That is not true, it's perfectly OK to use `this`, see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/api_scrolling.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of "scrollY":"120px", it should be "scrollY":"120". try without px.

Comment: It's OK to use `px`, see [scrollY](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly replace with the below initComplete function. It will work.

```
"initComplete": function () {
    $('#example').DataTable().row(2).scrollTo();
}
```

Note: 2 represents n-1 targetted row

Comment: It's perfectly OK to use `this`, see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/api_scrolling.html), no need to use `$('#example').DataTable()`.

Comment: But this.api() is not working. Kindly see the below sample code http://codepen.io/abbasak/pen/pePJGX

Comment: I get the same result if I use `this.api()`, it is preferred method because you don't necessarily have to use table ID.

Comment: Ok, I will try the same