# R shiny: choose a row to start displaying datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

below there is a shiny app that renders a `datatable` using `DT`. Rather than have the table start the display at row 1 I'd like to have the table render with a specific top row selected by the user (using `input$startRow` in this example).

E.g., if the user chose 50 in the slider the first row shown in the table would be row 50 rather than row 1.

Any tips for getting a dynamic starting row appreciated.

Edit for clarity: I do not want to subset the table, I want to display to begin at `input$startRow` but the user could scroll up and down and still see the entire dataset (e.g., `faithful` in this example).

Edit 2: It looks like the issue is that the `displayStart` option is what I want but that there is a [known bug](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/56048/scroller-statesave-bug-regression#latest) as of May 21 with `Scroller` starting the display mid table.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("faithful")

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Select the first row of the table to show"),
  sliderInput(inputId="startRow",
              label="Choose a row to start the datatable display",
              min = 1,
              max = 200,
              value = 100,
              step=5),
  # show a datatable
  h2("Show a table"),
  dataTableOutput("table1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    # use input$startRow to begin the table display?
    datatable(faithful,
              extensions = "Scroller", 
              options = list(scrollY = 300,
                             scroller = TRUE))
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There are some answers already on Stack Overflow which may give you a solution (or be adaptable, for you) - for example: [R Shiny - Scrolling to a given row of datatable with javascript callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47911673/12567365).

Answer (score 1):

Success. Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911673/r-shiny-scrolling-to-a-given-row-of-datatable-with-javascript-callback) in the comment. I was able to use `initComplete` to start the table on the row from `input$startRow`. This appears to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("faithful")

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Select the first row of the table to show"),
  sliderInput(inputId="startRow",
              label="Choose a row to start the datatable display",
              min = 1,
              max = 200,
              value = 10,
              step=5),
  # show a datatable
  h2("Show a table"),
  dataTableOutput("table1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(faithful,
              extensions = "Scroller",
              options = list(scrollY = 300,
                             scroller = TRUE,
                             initComplete  = JS('function() {this.api().table().scroller.toPosition(',
                                                input$startRow-1,');}')))})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `input$startRow` to begin the table display to generate the selected table.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("faithful")

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Select the first row of the table to show"),
  sliderInput(inputId="startRow",
              label="Choose a row to start the datatable display",
              min = 1,
              max = 200,
              value = 100,
              step=5),
  # show a datatable
  h2("Show a table"),
  dataTableOutput("table1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  topDF <- reactive({
    # use input$startRow to begin the table display
    topRow <- input$startRow
    
    selectedDf <- faithful[-(1:(topRow-1)), ]
    
    return(selectedDf)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({

    datatable(topDF(),
              extensions = "Scroller", 
              options = list(scrollY = 300,
                             scroller = TRUE))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. I still want the entire table to be available to the user. I just want the display to begin at `input$startRow`. The user could still scroll back to to row one. I will edit the question to me more clear.